# Lodash lazy chain doesn't work for me

Tags: javascript, lodash

What I expect from this code is `[1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`. The result is `[7, 8, 9]`. Where is my mistake? [Jsfiddle for this](http://jsfiddle.net/maximmig/xb90agw2/). Thanks.

```
var ar = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    arWrapper = _(ar),
    removedTypes = [3, 4],
    addedTypes = [7, 8, 9];

_.each(removedTypes, function (removedType) {    
    arWrapper = arWrapper.remove(function (type) {
        return type === removedType;
    });
});
_.each(addedTypes, function (addedType) {
    arWrapper = arWrapper.push(addedType);
});

console.log("%O", arWrapper.value());
```

Comment: `arWrapper.remove` returns a new array. Not a Lodash object.

Comment: @MathewFoscarini not when chained

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is not "idiomatic", since it relies on free variables here and there (and is "too imperative" overall):

The "better" solution would be:

```
var result = arWrapper.difference(removedTypes).union(addedTypes);
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xb90agw2/1/

As of your solution - it does not work because `.remove()` returns a collection of *removed* elements, not the collection with filtered out elements as you assume.

Comment: Thanks @zerkms. My "solution" was reduced for the sake of simplicity: actually I need more code in every `.each()` here. `.difference()` and `.union()` won't help. [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maximmig/xb90agw2/2/)

Comment: [The solution so far](http://jsfiddle.net/maximmig/xb90agw2/3/). Thanks for pointing out that `.remove()` won't help as well.

Comment: @MaximMig it's still ugly. If you asked properly we would help you to write it idiomatically. At the moment - there is no benefit of using lodash in your code: rewrite it with normal `forEach` and `if` and it would be just better.